# C# EntityFramework 5 Lose Reference on Insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, insert

I have got EF5 and want (have ...) to build a multitier application. EF is my persistance layer and I use WCF for my Clients. There is now a problem with my Business logic I dont understand exactly.

I have a method which should reserve something. when I send the Reservation to the datebase with .SaveChanges() everything is OK.

```
public bool bReservieren(Student oStudent, Korb oKorb, IEnumerable<Service> lServices, DateTime dtFrom, DateTime dtTo)
    {
        try
        {
            BeachChaireModelContainer context = new BeachChaireModelContainer();

            Reservierung newReservation = context.Reservation.Create();
            //Tried it with newReservation.Student = oStudent; But there is an 
            //error cause of the different context´s so I search the correct Student
            //again. (same with Korb)
            newReservation.Student = context.Student.Find(oStudent.Kartennummer);
            newReservierung.Korb = context.Korb.Find(oKorb.KID);
            newReservierung.dtVON = dtFrom;
            newReservierung.dtBIS = dtTo;
            newReservierung = context.Reservation.Add(newReservation);
               //This if isnt relevant yet. lService is null in my tests     
               if (lServices != null)
               {
                  foreach (var item in lServices)
                  {
                     newReservation.Service.Add(context.Service.Find(item.SeID));
                  }
               }

               context.SaveChanges();
               return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }

        return false;
    }
```

So, after I execute this and debug it there is a new reservation created with all the correct references! But when I try to get the Reservation again with something like:

```
//had to mention it is a new Methode with a new context, but this should
//be no Problem in my oppinion? 
var query = from it in context.Reservation
            select it;
```

I have the Student and the Korb Properties SET with null Values? In the database everything is correct. (The correct foreign keys are stored)

Anyone knows this behaviour?

In other words when I try to get the Reservation again with another context i couldn´t do something like:

```
String test = newReservation.Student.Surename;
```

Cause Student == null

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have lazy loading enabled (by making `Student` property virtual). If that is the case you have to `Include()` it when loading from database.

```
var query = from it in context.Reservation.Include("Student")
            select it;
```